# More readable date from @timestamp (logstash)

Tags: date, timestamp, logstash

How can I add new field containing date from @timestamp in more readable format (%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)?

UPDATE: It doesn't need to be done in logstash. Maybe someone know how to show @timestamp in that format (%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S) in Kibana?

Comment: What format do you want?

Comment: Why? Date formatting is something an presentation layer should do.